# Cocos3D template doesn't compile

Tags: templates, cocos3d

Just you know, I'm just starting with iOs and Objective-C (3days).

I'm currently making a 3D object viewer.
I want to be able to load a file and display it into a view. Then the user can rotates and zooms on it.

I have first build it with ninevehGL, but it appears that It doesn't support heavy files (>10M) so well.
I'm now trying to go for Cocos3D.

After i installed everything I have created a xcode project using the cocos3D 2.0 template.
This template should display (i guess) a 3D text "hello world".
But it doesn't even compile throwing me the following:
`-(void) updateBounds: (CGRect) bounds withDeviceOrientation: (ccDeviceOrientation) deviceOrientation;` <---- expected as a type

It appears that `(ccDeviceOrientation)` is not recognized as a type.
Would you help me with this ?

I have the project on gitHub [here](https://github.com/Micka33/3D-Viewer) under the folder COCOS3D

Also I'm using the followings version of cocos

```
   cocos2D: 2.0.0 8-Jul-2012
   cocos3D: cocos3d 0.7.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have, at the same time, posted my question on cocos2D forum, Bill Hollings has been kind enough the quickly reply, and pointed me that the versions of cocos2D and cocos3D i use can't work together.

[Here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/280732#post-439515) is the explanation and what to do.